# Function Overwriting Data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to read in a number of different text files with data and then graph the data.  My function works when reading in the data and I can get it graphed but with one small problem: when I run the program it appears to overwrite the data from the previous function call with the data of the current function thus creating a graph with all of the same data.  I have verified that the data is in fact different as can be seen when I call the matplotlib to graph the data after I have called each function and plots it all on figure 1.  Figure 2 however which is graphed at the end produces 4 lines exactly the same.  Can anyone point me as to why this happens and how I can shorten my code so that I am only calling matplotlib once at the end to graph all of the data?  A zip file of the data files can be found here so that the program will run:

```
#import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

flux = []

SEM = []

depth = []

c = 0

def data_reader(file_name, first_surface):

    del flux[:]

    del SEM[:]

    del depth[:]

    with open (file_name) as inf:

        lines = inf.readlines()

        for (i, line,) in enumerate(lines):

            if ' surface  %d' %first_surface in line:

                data = (lines[i+1].strip())

                fields = data.split()

                numbers = list(map(float,fields))  

                flux.append(numbers[0])

                SEM.append(numbers[1])

                first_surface += 1

                depth.append(first_surface - 101)                



    return (flux, SEM, first_surface)

data1 = data_reader('concrete_40billion.txt', 101)
flux_1 = data1[0]
SEM_1 = data1[1]

plt.figure(1)
plt.rcParams['legend.loc'] = 'best'
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=None)
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=None)
plt.plot(depth, flux_1, 'k')
plt.loglog()
plt.hold(True)
print('plots created')
plt.show()

data2 = data_reader('du_1m_20billion.txt', 101)
flux_2 = data2[0]
SEM_2 = data2[1]

plt.figure(1)
plt.rcParams['legend.loc'] = 'best'
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=None)
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=None)
plt.plot(depth, flux_2, 'g')
plt.loglog()
plt.hold(True)
print('plots created')
plt.show()

data3 = data_reader('du_2m_20billion.txt', 101)
flux_3 = data3[0]
SEM_3 = data3[1]

plt.figure(1)
plt.rcParams['legend.loc'] = 'best'
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=None)
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=None)
plt.plot(depth, flux_3, 'b')
plt.loglog()
plt.hold(True)
print('plots created')
plt.show()

data4 = data_reader('du_3cm_20billion.txt', 101)
flux_4 = data4[0]
SEM_4 = data4[1]

plt.figure(1)
plt.rcParams['legend.loc'] = 'best'
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=None)
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=None)
plt.plot(depth, flux_4, 'r')
plt.loglog()
plt.hold(True)
print('plots created')
plt.show()

#difference = [a - b for a,b in zip(flux_1, flux_2)]
#print difference

plt.rcParams['legend.loc'] = 'best'
plt.figure(2)
#plt.xlim(0, 0.04)
#plt.ylim(0, 7000)
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=None)
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=None)
plt.plot(depth, flux_1, 'k',label='flux 1')
plt.plot(depth, flux_2, 'g', label='flux 2')
plt.plot(depth, flux_3, 'b', label='flux 3')
plt.plot(depth, flux_4, 'r', label='flux 4')
plt.xlabel('Depth (cm)')
plt.ylabel('Flux (particles/cm^2*s)')
plt.loglog()
plt.legend()
print('plots created')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Any reason to use [dot] on the link?

Comment: Some sites block websites so I changed the dot to [dot] so it would go through.  Looks like this site doesn't so I changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having issues due to the fact that your function is closing over `flux`, `SEM` and `depth` so you are mucking up the returned values with the `del`s.

`flux` is a global mutable list, each pass through your function your clear the contents of `flux`, re-fill it, and then return a reference to `flux` which you then store as `flux_n`. That is *all* of your `flux_n` point at the same underlying `list` object.  The same applies for `SEM_n`.

When you plot using `matplotlib` that data gets copied so your existing graphs are not affected once you make them.

Try :

```
def data_reader(file_name, first_surface):
    flux = []
    SEM = []
    depth = []

    with open (file_name) as inf:
        lines = inf.readlines()
        for (i, line,) in enumerate(lines):
            if ' surface  %d' %first_surface in line:
                data = (lines[i+1].strip())
                fields = data.split()
                numbers = list(map(float,fields))  
                flux.append(numbers[0])
                SEM.append(numbers[1])
                first_surface += 1
                depth.append(first_surface - 101)                

    return (flux, SEM, first_surface)
```

Comment: Awesome makes perfect sense.  Thanks for your help!